# bash script does not continue into for loop

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new with bash scripting and I'm struggling with an elif statement. I can't get the script to go into the for loop, it simply cuts off at the read part and stops executing. I was wondering if anyone can help, thanks in advance. Just to clarify, my code should be accepting two command-line arguments however if only one command is given then the code should print an error message asking for the second value to be given, once this value is given it will use the first command-line argument and the second value given after the error message and use these values in the for loop. values being passed to $1 and val1 should simply be integers side note: After entering the second value (val1) this is when it just stops and doesn't kick into the for loop as I want it to.

```sh
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]; then  #checks if number of arguments is 1
        read -p "Please enter another value" val1 #prints error message
        for((i=($1+($1%2));i<($val1-3);i+=2));do  #for loop lists all even numbers
```

Comment: I'd want to know what values the `for` loop has to work with, ie, after the `read` and before the `for...`, add `echo ".${1}.${val1}."` (the periods are there as delimiters); also, what do you mean by 'it just stops' ... does the script exit? does the script hang? does any part of the rest of the script get executed? even if we know `$1` and `$val1` are valid integers, it'll be hard to say what the issue is since we don't have a **complete** set of code with which to reproduce the issue

Comment: What do you mean by "it just stops" ? What do you see with `bash -vx yourscript`?

Comment: So I input bash fileName.sh 1 (1 being my first value which is a command-line value) since I would need two command-line values, read statement is used to print asking the user to enter another value which should be stored in val1. Once this message prints i enter another integer like 20 but then the script just exits and does not carry on into the for loop. @jhnc @ markp-fuso

Comment: What do you see when you add `-vx` as requested?

Comment: hi, thanks so much for the help but I've managed to fix the error, I think the for loop was just not nested properly